# I'm trying to sort an array by counting the elements and then sort them again "counting sort"

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

I'm trying to sort the array by making another array with size of the maximum number in the array I want to sort, then each time I find the number I ++ the index of that number..ex: the main array is {5,3,8,1,2,3}
the other array {0,1,1,2,0,1,0,0,1}
then my sorted array will be like {1,2,3,3,5,8} I have no idea why my code is not working any help please?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int findmax(int a[], int size){
int max = a[0];
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    if (max < a[i])
        max = a[i];
return max;
}

 void sort(int a[], int n){
 int max = findmax(a, n);
int *arr;
arr = new int[max+1];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    arr[a[i]]++;
}
for (int k = 0; k < n;){
    for (int l = 0; l <= max; l++)  {
        while (arr[l] != 0){
            a[k] = l;
            arr[l]--;
            k++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you *really* should be doing is to step through the code line by line in a debugger. That way you will easily see what the problem is.

But since I started writing this I might as well post it as an answer.

The problem is that the array you allocate and assign to `arr` is not initialized, its contents is *indeterminate*. And using uninitialized data is *undefined behavior*.

What's really is happening is that the data you allocate will be seemingly random, and most likely none of it will be zero. That leads to your counts being all wrong.

The solution is to clear the memory you allocate before counting values:

```
std::fill(arr, arr + max + 1, 0);
```